# HTTPS GET API call in node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, api, https

Im new to node.js and consuming API's. Im following this [tutorial](https://nodejs.dev/making-http-requests-with-nodejs) for how to make a GET request but I keep getting this error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:800
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',   syscall: 'connect',
>   address: '127.0.0.1',   port: 800 }

I'm not sure what to do now, any feedback is appreciated!

> My 'DistributionList.js' file

```
const https = require("https");

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://SomeApi.com/distributionLists',
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer xyz",
        Accept: "application/json"
    }
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

    res.on('data', d => {
      process.stdout.write(d)
    })
})

req.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error)
})

req.end()
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing the URL and replacing it with a host and path worked for me!

```
const https = require("https");

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    host : 'SomeApi.com',
    path:  '/distributionLists',
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer xyz",
        Accept: "application/json"
    }
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

    res.on('data', d => {
      process.stdout.write(d)
    })
})

req.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error)
})

req.end()
```

Comment: exactly.  you can use https.request(url, res...  but as soon as you want to include headers, method, etc (ie, other options), then you have to use host and path.